# Is there any free WebUI tools for administrating and monitoring MongoDb server instance similar to Atlas Cloud?

Tags: mongodb, vps, dashboard, database-administration, mongodb-atlas

I am searching for tool, which should provide collections overview, queries to them, replicas configurations, instance performance dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for zabbix as elementary monitoring. However for querying the DB for data you need to use custom shell scripts or metric reporting tools to get that information